# Have the Margin on Each Monitor in Openbox

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, opensuse, openbox

I have moved to Openbox after using i3-gaps for a while, everything is going well but I want to have an outer margin applied just like in i3. I can specify a margin but it doesn't behave exactly how I want it to, here is a rough diagram of my multi-monitor setup with the margins in red;

[how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nImcu.png) (the margin is applied all around to the combined three monitors)

I want it to behave like it did in i3, here is the rough diagram of my multi-monitor setup with the margins in red where the margins are actually where I want them to be;

[how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1YK0.png) (the margin is applied to be around each monitor individually)

Is there any way to resolve this or will I have to just deal with it? If it helps I have an NVIDIA 1660ti, with driver version `440.64`.